# Rails Query for models that contain both/multiple associations

Tags: sql, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model Book and Books has_many Authors.  I would like to find all the books that have  associations with two different authors.  The relationship is HABTM.

To find the number of books with one author's name I am using

```
Book.includes(:authors).where('authors.name = ?', 'Joe Smith').references(:author).count
```

I have tried adding the second to the end like this

```
Book.includes(:authors).where('authors.name = ?', 'Joe Smith').references(:author).includes(:authors).where('authors.name = ?', 'Dave Jones').references(:author).count
```

And this

```
Book.includes(:authors).where('authors.name = ?', 'Joe Smith').references(:author).where('authors.name = ?', 'Dave Jones').references(:author).count
```

And have tried adding an && statement

```
Book.includes(:authors).where('authors.name = ?', 'Joe Smith' && 'Dave Jones').references(:author).count
```

And this

```
Book.includes(:authors).where('authors.name = ?', 'Joe Smith' && 'authors.name = ?', 'Dave Jones').references(:author).count
```

None have worked...

How can I include books that have BOTH that author AND another author?

Seems straight forward, but I am having some issues getting the query to work.  If one query is not the answer and I need to do a query and then iterate through or something then that would be helpful guidance as well.

Thanks!

Comment: are you saying you want to search for 2 authors at the same time? You can do this with an `Array` e.g. `.where(authors:{name:['Joe Smith','James Brown']})` which will create an `IN(...)` Statement. Or do you want to find books that include both authors exclusively?

Comment: @engineersmnky I would like the query to return an array of books that have BOTH author associations.

Comment: can you please give some info on your book - author relation ?

Comment: @xlembouras yes of course and I will add to the question as well.  The relationship is many to many.

Comment: is it a habtm relation or a has_many through ? the last can be very helpful in your case.

Comment: @xlembouras HABTM...thank you for helping me clarify, I should have included that.